# How to use decision tree to calculate the probability of an event?

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a good which is estimated to have 60% chance of high demand, and 40% chance of low demand.

I have a possibility to make a market study to predict the nature of demand of a good.
The good has either high demand, or low demand.

In the past, these studies have been know to **predict a high demand in 95% of the cases where a high demand has actually been observed**.

**Also, a high demand has been predicted in 15% of the cases where a low demand has actually been observed.**

I'm at a lost here; how do I make any sense of this? What's the deal here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common terms for the bold concepts are *true positive* and *false positive*, respectively. According to the first statement, given that the good has a high demand, the studies predict with a 95% chance of correctness (true positive). The second statement says that given the good has a low demand, the studies predict incorrectly with a 15% chance (false positive).

Although there is no direct question in your problem, I hope this paraphrases it well enough.

Answer (score 0):

So we have a high demand with $60\%$, a low demand with $40\%$. When we observe a high demand, there is a $95\%$ chance of predicting a high demand. Similarly, high demand is predicted in $15\%$ of the observations when low demand is observed.

So the probability that high demand is predicted is: $0.6 * 0.95 + 0.4 * 0.15$. Do you see how I got that? Take the probability of a high demand and multiply it by the probability of predicting a high demand. Do the same for predicting a high demand, but when a low demand is observed. The two cases are disjoint, so add them.

We can similarly calculate the probability of predicting a low demand: $0.6 * 0.05 + 0.4 * 0.85$.

Answer (score 0):

The deal's simple. You perform a market study that gives you a set of probabilities for success and failure. Based on the outcome of the market study, you would be making a decision as to whether the item will be released into the market or not.

Let P(A) be prob of high demand, P(B) is low demand.
Let P(X) be prob of market study predicting high demand, P(Y) be prob of market study predicting low demand.

What you have are-  P(A)=0.6, P(B)= 0.4
Then you have conditional probabilities given, ie, P(X|A) = 0.95 (read as, probability of X given A has happened), P(Y|A) = 0.05, P(X|B) = 0.15, P(Y|B)=0.85

From this, use the Bayes Rule for joint/conditional/posterior probabilities calculation. Since there is no question as such, I'm unsure what you require further.